# WCF service occasionally hangs on synchronous calls despite the quick response from the service

Tags: c#, debugging, wcf, timeout

I am working with a complex WCF service/client application, where both the service and client perform various tasks. Providing a code sample might not be useful in this context.

I have encountered an issue where synchronous calls to the service sometimes hang for no apparent reason. The client can call the service either asynchronously (using async Tasks) or synchronously on the UI thread.

The problem occurs when making a simple synchronous call to the service. The logs show the following sequence:

1. Client calls `Service.MethodA`.
2. Service logs `MethodA call Start`.
3. Service logs `MethodA process end duration (~5ms)` (this log is just before the return for the client).
4. Client waits for the response... but after a 5-minute timeout, it reports that the service never responded and retries the call.

The same call sometimes works perfectly fine, while other times it encounters the issue mentioned above. I am not sure where to start in order to debug this problem. Any suggestions on what I should investigate or potential causes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whether the server process is blocked or waiting for too many server threads before returning data.

Comment: As i have multiple client and no idéa how many server thread was in during the bug is their a way to log the WCF server status? to see if it's the problem?

Comment: Try incrementally increasing the number of simultaneous requests for data from multiple clients to see when this problem occurs.